# Excel Pivot - How to apply banded rows or columns based on a higher level?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

While working with an Excel pivot table that has 2 fields selected for columns, I can use the *Banded Columns* checkbox under *Pivot Table Style Options* to apply alternating colors to columns.

When applied, this style always alternates colors of every other column. For example in the screenshot below you can see that every other column is colored. But I don't want to color based on X1, X2, Y1, Y2, etc. I want different groups to have different colored columns so X1, X2 should have a color; Y1, Y2, Y3 should have a different color and Z1, Z2 should have the same color as Xs.

[image]

Please notice that Groups X, Y, Z have different number of sub elements so changing *Stripe Size* in style options cannot help.

The very same example could be changed to refer to rows instead of columns.

The short question is: How can I alternate colors based on a higher level dimension field value?

Comment: Hi @e-mre,, select PT,, check Design TAB, click the pallet, you find New Pivot Table Style,, help U to highlight parts of PT or U may use Conditional Formatting also. For ex. select entire PT,, New Rule should `=OR(B$3="Y1",B$3="Y2",B$3="Y3")`,, will works for entire column has header like Y1, Y2 & Y3 ☺

Comment: @RajeshS, I know I can create a new pivot style but I can't see how that will help me to format cells accoding to their rows or column values? About Conditional Formatting: To use your solution, I will need to define rules for all possible X, Y, Z values, which is not a viable option. The table I sent in the question is a sample. My actual table is a much much larger one.

Comment: ,, other than Style the possible is what I've suggested for Ys & Xs the Conditional format,, another rapid one is Macro (the VBA code) but the code is to define for Conditional / Style formatting,, I don't think any other is left !!